# Android: JSONException caught while trying to retrieve data from server

Tags: php, android, json

I'm now writing a code to retrieve JSON array from server. For the Android-side, I'm using OkHttp3 API and here's the part of my code.

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String strResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.i(TAG, strResponse);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResponse);
                    boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");

                    if(!error) {
                        String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
                        JSONArray people = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
                        final String name = people.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "it works! " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        final String strError = jsonObject.getString("error_msg");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "JSONException caught: " + e.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } finally {
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is the PHP file which the above code is connected to.

```
<?php

// when you get a post request with a name called 'search_name'
if(isset($_POST['search_name'])) {

    // get the name value
    $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];

    require_once 'include/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_Connect();
    $conn = $db->connect();

    $users = array("error" => FALSE);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT unique_id, name, email from users where name LIKE '%$search_name%'");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    // if user with the queried name exists
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $row_array["uid"] = $row["unique_id"];
            $row_array["users"]["name"] = $row['name'];
            $row_array["users"]["email"] = $row['email'];
            array_push($users, $row_array);
        }
        echo json_encode($users);
    } else {
        $stmt->close();
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "No matching users found.";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} 

// if the post request is not what this file is supposed to work with
else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

So, as I mentioned above already, I want to retrieve an array of names and emails from the MySQL database. In order to do that, I send a POST request to the PHP URL, and then the PHP file processes the statement to retrieve the data which meet the condition, puts them into the array, encodes the array into JSON and echoes that.

Then the Android side's `onResponse()` method above receives the response and takes the next step. This is what I have done so far, but I'm now stuck.

The process now ends up catching the `JSONException`. Can somebody help me find out the reason?

**Added**

Here's the Log with the `strResponse`.

02-02 23:14:26.203 20668-24366/com.marshall.authentication I/MainActivity:

```
    <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in <b>/storage/h3/859/644859/public_html/searchfriends.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
                                                                           {"error":true,"error_msg":"No matching users found."}
02-02 23:14:26.203 20668-20668/com.marshall.authentication I/MainActivity: JSONException caught: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

According to the `Log`, I'm now starting to believe that the problem is due to the wrong parameters in the `bind_param()` function in the PHP file. How should I fix it then?

Comment: please post the error log, or the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Your problem seems to be here: LIKE '%$name%'") --> it should be LIKE :name and `%` wild card sign should be inside the variable. e.g. '%' . $name . '%'

Comment: I tested that statement at `phpMyAdmin` and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: `JSONException caught while trying to retrieve data from server`. No not then. The data is retrieved ok from the server. You have the exception when you try to make a json object from the data. You better first check if the data is valid.

Comment: @greenapps can you suggest me any solutions? I spent hours dealing with this issue today and I still cannot get to the point yet..

Comment: `String strResponse = response.body().string();`. That is the json text that was send by php. Before you use it first check if it is valid. Is it null? Did you log it to see if it looks like json?

Comment: Dont use a database and an insert before you have running all. Better just let the php script return some predetermined json and check if you receive that. Just echo the parameters so you know if all data is received well by the script. You want too much at once and at the moment you don't know what happens where.

Comment: @greenapps I just added the Log. can you check it out?

Comment: @MarshallS.Lee try replacing the lines in your code with my answer. phpmyadmin is not the same as PDO in php script. And check if the database is responding by dumping the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT unique_id, name, email from users where name LIKE :name");
$stmt->bind_param(":name", '%' . str_replace('%', '\%', $name) . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

In case you want to check if the data from the database is what you expect. Dump it:

```
var_dump($response);
```